# Find the largest possible delta given epsilon

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

> Consider the function $g:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x) = x^2$. For each $a\geq 1$ find the largest possible value of  $\delta > 0$ such that the following holds: $$x\geq 1\space \text{with}\space|x-a|<\delta \implies|x^2-a^2|<1.$$

I started by playing with the right hand side:

$$|x^2-a^2|=|(x-a)(x+a)|$$
$$=|x-a||x+a|$$
$$<\delta|x+a| = 1$$

We have the largest possible value of delta when $|x+a| $ is minimal (this is obvious since $\delta=1/|x+a|$). $|x+a|$ is minimal when both $x$ and $a$ are minimal, which by definition is when they both equal $1$. So: 
$$\delta_{max}|2|=1$$
$$\delta_{max} = \frac{1}{|2|}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Is this correct? I have a memory of doing this type of question previously and it being more difficult to find delta. I can't find a reason why this isn't correct, though.

Comment: You could write $x+a$ instead of $|x+a|$ since you know $x,a\geqslant 1$. I think the words you're looking for are minimum and maximum, but I'll check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct. If $|x-a| < \delta$ we have
$$|x^2-a^2| = |x-a||x+a| \le |x-a|(|x-a|+2a) < \delta(\delta + 2a)$$

where both inequalities are sharp. Solving the equation $\delta(\delta+2a) = 1$ we get the positive solution
$$\delta_{\max} := -a + \sqrt{a^2+1}$$

which is the desired largest possible delta.

Indeed, for $\delta > \delta_{\max}$ consider $x = \sqrt{a^2+1}$. Then
$$|x-a| = -a+\sqrt{a^2+1} < \delta$$
but $|x^2-a^2| = 1$.

Comment: But the requirement is that $|x^2-a^2|<1$? How can $|x^2-a^2| =1$?

Comment: @yerman Precisely, that's why $\delta > -a + \sqrt{a^2+1}$ is too big.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks.